# Splash screen attempt just shows a black screen

Tags: android, splash-screen

I've tried to implement a splash screen to my app but it just shows me a black screen for the amount of time that i told him to..

Manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".SplashScreen"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Java:

```
public class SplashScreen extends FragmentActivity {

    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,RSR_Revalidatieservice.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        },SPLASH_TIME_OUT);

    }
}
```

XML:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SplashScreen">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/splash_logo_rsr" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/splash_logo" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I'm only trying to show a splash screen for about 3 seconds so no need to "load" app or so in background, i just wanted a cool launcher effect.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:
 `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` from your manifest
with:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```

Comment: Apptheme cannot be resolved as a symbol... Tried using @android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar but it didn't work !

Comment: Instead of apptheme use Theme

Comment: Now it's showing me a white screen without the two imageview... Still that's a progress

Comment: @PhilémonRoubaud instead of src compat set src